# How can I create a compound bubble and pie chart?

Tags: charts, data-visualization

I'm looking for a way to create a compound bubble and pie chart likes this one:

[image]

I know that ManyEyes could do it, but I don't want to upload my dataset to the public. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Software and purchasing recommendations are off topic. I've reworded you question to remove the software request in order to avoid it being closed as off topic. Hopefully the meaning is still intact. If not, please [edit] it but avoid asking for software recommendations.

Comment: Why are you interested in this type of chart?  It's very difficult to get any meaningful analysis from it-it combines the worst of pie charts with more pie charts (its notoriously difficult to compare angles and areas). Would you consider a different chart type? If you're set on this, you may check Tableau, it has some unique chart types like this.

Comment: @dav I'm open to other chart types, but I couldn't think of a better one.

Answer (score 0):

The only places I've seen compound bubble pie charts are Excel and the [ZingChart charting library](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bubble-pie/).